# Animate Javascript Canvas while in recursive calculation

Tags: javascript, canvas, recursion, backtracking, latin-square

I'm trying to animate a solution to the [latin-square-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) in javascript.

To do so, I wrote the recursive backtracking algorithm below.

Solving the problem is initiated by calling `search(0,0)` and it works just fine, displaying a solution after calculating. But I want it to show an animation on it's progress, in terms of redrawing the whole canvas, after changing the colour of one square.

I tried to incoorporate many of the solutions to similar problems, found on stackoverflow or in tutorials about canvas gameloops. Neither of them worked for me, so I'm presenting the javascript code as close as possible to my pseudo-code algorithm (without any `setTimeout`'s or `requestAnimationFrame`'s)

[Here's a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezstfj9f/2/) containing all the code.

```js
function search(i, j){
    if (latinSquare[i][j] != -1){
        //this square is predefined, skip it
        searchNext(i, j);
    } else {
        var colour = latinSquare[i][j];
        while(colour < n-1){
            colour = colour + 1;
            latinSquare[i][j] = colour;
            //redraw the whole canvas
            drawLatinSquare();
            //check if curent constellation is legal
            var legal = true;
            for (var k = 0; k < n; k++){
                if (k != i){
                    if (latinSquare[k][j] == colour){
                        legal = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (k != j){
                    if (latinSquare[i][k] == colour){
                        legal = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (legal){
                searchNext(i, j);
                if (window.found) return;
            }
        }
        latinSquare[i][j] = -1;
    }   
}

function searchNext(i, j){
    if (i < n-1){
        //proceed horizontally
        search(i+1, j);
    } else {
        if (j < n-1){
            //proceed in the next row
            search(0, j+1);
        } else {
            //we're done
            window.found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to animate each step, you'll need to rewrite your algorithm into a purely recursive version - no `while`, no `for` loops. Then you can trivially insert `setTimeout`s with callbacks for the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, an array is created to hold each iteration of the `latinSquare` arrays.  The timeout interval is a function of the length of the array.

An advantage of this method is that the animation doesn't start until all the calculations are completed, so it runs quite quickly (assuming a solution is found):

```
var lsa= [];

function drawLatinSquare() {
  var l= [];
  for(var i = 0 ; i < latinSquare.length ; i++) {
    l.push(latinSquare[i].slice());
  }      
  lsa.push(l);
  setTimeout(function() {
    var ls= lsa.shift();
    ctx.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ctx.lineWidth= 1;
    //draw the grid
    for (var i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0,i*21 + 0.5);
      ctx.lineTo((n*(21)+1),i*21 + 0.5);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < n + 1; j++){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(j*21 + 0.5,0);
      ctx.lineTo(j*21 + 0.5,(n*(21)+1));
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    //draw the squares
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
        colour = ls[i][j];
        if (colour == -1){
          colour = "#FFFFFF";
        } else {
          colour = colours[colour];
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = colour;
        ctx.fillRect((i*21)+1.5,(j*21)+1.5,20,20);
      }
    }
  },10*lsa.length);
} //drawLatinSquare
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jp9sqqx5/)

Comment: Since I do not really need to draw _while_ calculating, this is the solution I'm going to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the call to the main compute function to have it display then delay the call to the actual compute function :

```
function search(i,j) {
    drawLatinSquare();
    setTimeout(function() { _search(i,j)} , 15);
}

function _search(i, j){
  //... your real search function
```

issue being that there are too many combinations to see them all for a 'big' n : you should make a choice about what you want to show i fear.

Also if i was you i'd do a first pass to see the number of iterations, so that you can display a progress bar or like.

https://jsfiddle.net/ezstfj9f/4/

Comment: I had a very similar solution but was very disappointed with its performance. Like in your solution, I could not understand why its slowing down after a while and leaving visited cells blank.